# Сбивается анимация

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

У меня есть элемент управления StackPanel, в нем находятся Image расположенный по центру по вертикали и горизонтали.

Есть 2 события MouseMove и MouseLeave они привязаны к StackPanel.
Когда я навожу мышь на Image срабатывает анимация, но когда я увожу мышь с Image идет обратный процесс анимации который находится в MouseLeave(StackPanel). Тобишь анимация сбивается, хотя Image находится в StackPanel.
Как мне сделать так чтобы при отвода курсора от Image не вызывался метод MouseLeave в StackPanel?
Помогите плз!

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Background="Red" MouseMove="StackPanel_MouseMove" MouseLeave="StackPanel_MouseLeave">
        <Image x:Name="Image1" Source="icons8-папка-50.png" Opacity="0.5" Margin="0, 50, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

```
private void StackPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(Image1.Opacity, 1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Image1.BeginAnimation(Image.OpacityProperty, anim);
    }

    private void StackPanel_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(Image1.Opacity, 0.5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Image1.BeginAnimation(Image.OpacityProperty, anim);
    }
```

Comment: Приведите код для воспроизведения проблемы, пока не совсем понятно что требуется

Comment: Если быстро двигать мышь влево/вправо то эффект анимации как будто сбивается из его тайминга.
Попробуйте, увидите что прозрачность картинки при хаотично быстром движении мыши над StackPanel станет =1 не за одну секунду времени как в указано в коде.
Прошу прошения если не могу внятно объяснить!)

Comment: Если я правильно понят, то уберите From из анимации и будет счастье. А вообще, мой вам совет - создавайте анимацию там, где ей место (XAML разметка!).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!